# How to add custom font for Avada WordPress Theme

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, themes

I want to use a custom font for my website which uses WordPress and Avada theme,
I introduced the font via typography custom font option. 
But since its not listed on the Google or Standard fonts, I can't apply it on the headings or title or body.

How can I add a new font to the list of fonts in Avada theme and use it for different sections of the website?

or if I can change the css, which css and where I can change the fonts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by editing the `style.css` in the `themes\avada` directory and imported my font via the `font-face`, plus I selected `none` for the font selection boxes in the typography section of the theme options otherwise they override my fonts

Actually the order of styles being applied is: style.css -> options in the theme options -> custom styles in the theme options

don't rely on editing `avada.css` which is dynamically generated after changing the theme options.

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to change the CSS -- it will be located inside the theme directory, and the file will normally be called `styles.css`. If you [import your font into the css file](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp), you should be able to apply your Persian font instead of the default.

Comment: thank you, your solutions is close to the way I found and described in my answer

Comment: If this was the solution you were looking for, could you please accept my answer? Glad I was able to help :)

Comment: In fact I had solved the problem before I see your comment, however I appreciate it but I have already answered the question by myself which is the exact steps and selecting of none for the default value of fonts is important, I can vote your answer up, thank you